# Spring and webservice

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jackson

I wanted make a web-service with spring. Something easy and bit a bit make it more complex. Currently I have the same logic with Symphony2 and Mongodb, the idea is have a lot of request per second through one web-service.

The point is migrate the actual code in php to Java and I would like do it with spring. Until I understand for the REST service I could install:

- jersey
- with spring MVC directly
- Jackson

Which one is the best, more actual, fast, easy .... ? In other site, I was trying to use my actual DB (Mongo) with Hibernate but I got a several problems. Then, my question here is,Should I choose other DB? Should I remove Hibernate? how hibernate penalize the latency I mean how much time i will lost if I use or not hibernate. If you use Doctrine or not for example ( hibernate=Doctrine "more or less" in PHP ) there is a difference for the time from you send the request to the webservice and you get the answer from it.

I finally I use hibernate what db:

- MySql
- PostgreSQL
- Oracle

The idea is make a project related with the stock market, so a lot of changes with currencies and new insert , updates and select in the db in the same time. When more close to "real time" better.

Thanks for your help! I am sorry for the questions I am more php boy trying to change to java :)

Comment: Why would you use hibernate with mongodb?

Comment: Well is only because my actual logic is with mongo + DoctrineMongo, Should I remove the MongoDb? but then ... which db I should choose I know that for example Mysql is not as fast as is mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a question, but if it were me and Spring was a set requirement:

I'd start by setting up a Spring application via [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) or [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/), add some controllers taking and sending JSON via the [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (this integrates nicely with Spring) and use [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) to push my data into [Redis](http://redis.io/), an in-memory storage ([Spring Data Redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/)). You will have to care about persistence, but might be able to do that asynchronously from time to time (e.g. using [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)). If these controller mappings don't suffice your use case and you really want to go REST, there is also a [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) subproject to expose your data as “RESTful endpoints“. This should integrate nicely with the storage/persistence layer (never used this myself).

Don't really know about the Hibernate penalty and I think this is something you should measure yourself. However, it is always a good idea to keep the setup as simple as possible, so try starting without Hibernate. Of course, it strongly depends on your data if you want to/need to/should use an ORM. Speaking of simple: nothing about this is simple, you already have lots of libraries and dependencies on board. There seems to be a Spring project for everything these days, but I know nothing about the maturity of all those Spring Data projects.

In general (and in theory): If you use the right abstractions, you should be able to migrate to a different persistence provider later on if you need to because of measured performance bottlenecks.